# Stroke and Fill Shapes in Cocos2dx

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x

I am looking for a feature in Cocos2dx that is readily available in a couple presentation frameworks I have used.

**Stroke and Fill Brushes**

Rich shape rendering allows one to specify a shape (ellipse, rectangle, custom polygon, custom shape with curves, etc.), a location, a size, a stroke brush and a fill brush then render.

Below is an example of the feature. In this case the shape is a star with a variety of brushes.

[Brush Varieties for Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq8V6.png)
I have searched for such functionality in Cocos2dx but the closest I could find is polygon rendering with a solid color stroke and fill. I used it and it worked well but is not the "smart brush" I am looking for.

**Brush Animation**

Second feature I am looking for is the ability to animate the brushes. In this example, the fill brush starts off green then either instantly changes to or animates to yellow. This is done by altering properties of the shape, not recreating.

[Brush Animation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucHO8.png)

Is this possible in Cocos2dx?  If not, could you provide suggestions about how I might code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think CCSprite/CCLayerColor/CCLayerGradient with CCClippingNode can simulate the "smart brush", and tintTo/tintBy action of CCSprite/CCLayerColor can change color without destroying the object